# Error message using Ralink 802.11 n WLAN in Backtrack 5 R3

Tags: backtrack-linux

In Window7 Ultimate (32 bit) I run Backtrack 5 R3 in VMware workstation and connect via Wi-Fi with a TP-LINK wireless network adapter. I always see this sentence:

> The connection for the USB device "Ralink 802.11 n WlAN" was
>   unsuccesful. The device is currently in use.

Why? How to change my settings in VMware workstation or Backtrack?